# how to install angular/cli in ubuntu 18 LTS

Tags: node.js, angular, angular-cli

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RDAOn.png)I'm unable to install angular/CLI into my ubuntu 18 LTS environment. When a tried to install by using such command which was mention at the official website then it gives me numerous errors and warnings but till now angular/CLI nothing has installed.I've mentioned my terminal errors and warnings below
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/btITp.png)

Comment: anyone please reply me

Answer (score 0):

It seems Permission Denied to access `/usr/local/lib/`.

Try with root sudo ,

```
sudo npm install -g @angular/cli
```

If not success try with --force command

```
sudo npm install -g -f angular-cli
```

Comment: the problem has not resolved till now it gives the same errors and  warnings: